# Distinct does not remove the duplicated item?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I tried linq to remove duplicate item:

```
   var MyItems = (from b in this.result
               select new Item{ Name = b.Name, ID = b.ID }).Distinct();
```

The I checked the result, it is not removed the duplicated items. 
How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Duplicate by which criteria? Have you done an override of `Equals` in `Item`?

Comment: Define "Duplicate" in this context - same ID? You will probably have to provide an equality comparer.

Comment: Thanks, guys. Working now after override Equals and GetHashCode.

Answer (score 5):

By default, `Distinct()` uses `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`, which has the following rules:

> The default equality comparer, Default, is used to compare values of the types that implement the IEquatable generic interface. To compare a custom data type, you need to implement this interface and provide your own GetHashCode and Equals methods for the type.

In your case, this means `Item` needs to implement `IEquatable<Item>`.

Alternatively, you can use the [overload of `Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx) which takes an `IEqualityComparer<T>` directly.

Comment: Implementing both .equals() and .hashCode() also worked in Java!

Answer (score 3):

You can pass Distinct() a comparer object:

```
var MyItems = (from b in this.result
           select new Item{ Name = b.Name, ID = b.ID }).Distinct(new ItemComparer());
```

Here is an example of the custom comparer class

```
// Custom comparer for the Item class
class ItemComparer: IEqualityComparer<Product>
{
    // Items are equal if their names and IDs are equal.
    public bool Equals(Item x, Item y)
    {

        //Check whether the compared objects reference the same data.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        //Check whether any of the compared objects is null.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;

    //Check whether the items' properties are equal.
    return x.ID == y.ID && x.Name == y.Name;
    }

    // If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects 
    // then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects.

    public int GetHashCode(Item item)
    {
        //Check whether the object is null
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(item, null)) return 0;

        //Get hash code for the Name field if it is not null.
        int hashItemName = item.Name == null ? 0 : item.Name.GetHashCode();

        //Get hash code for the ID field.
        int hashItemID = item.ID.GetHashCode();

        //Calculate the hash code for the item.
        return hashItemName ^ hashItemID;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Regular `Distinct()` returns elements from a collection by using the default equality comparer.

You can use custom [comparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx) for this:

```
// modified example from docs, not tested
class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<Item>
{
    // Items are equal if their ids are equal.
    public bool Equals(Item x, Item y)
    {

        // Check whether the compared objects reference the same data.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        // Check whether any of the compared objects is null.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;

        //Check whether the items properties are equal.
        return x.ID == y.ID;
    }

    // If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects 
    // then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects.

    public int GetHashCode(Product product)
    {
        //Check whether the object is null
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(item, null)) return 0;

        //Get hash code for the ID field.
        int hashProductId = product.ID.GetHashCode();

        return hashProductId;
    }

}

var myItems = (from b in this.result
               select new Item{ Name = b.Name, ID = b.ID }).Distinct(new MyComparer());
```

Answer (score 1):

As you're comparing objects, not primitives, you're going to have to do some work to define what `Distinct` means.

Have a look at the `Distinct` override that includes `IEqualityComparer`:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't know how you're using the `Items` after this, I'm gambling here.

If really only need the ID-Name pair, you can use an anonymous type and get the comparison for free:

```
var MyItems = (from b in this.result
               select new { b.Name, b.ID }).Distinct();
```

After this (and once again assuming *all you need is the Name-ID pair*), the resulting object will have properties you need:

```
foreach(var item in MyItems)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", item.ID, item.Name);
```

---

Quoting MSDN on [C# Anonymous Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx):

> Because the Equals and GetHashCode methods on anonymous types are defined in terms of the Equals and GetHashcode methods of the properties, two instances of the same anonymous type are equal only if all their properties are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Enumerable.Distinct Method (IEnumerable) Returns distinct elements from a sequence by using the default equality comparer to compare values.

please check this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx

Answer (score -4):

You need add new items to List, use foreach exam:

```
foreach(var _item in result.Distinct()){
//Code here
}
```

ok :)